# Python Selenium driver.get maximum arguments reached?

Tags: python, json, selenium

I have a issue with try to pull in JSON data in driver.get using selenium. As you can see below the error I'm getting is that I can't use more then 2 agruments with this method.

```
for d in data["screen"]:
    display = Display(visible=1, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://",d["server"],"/test",sep='')

TypeError: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

This makes me think that this isn't the right method for getting varibale data into the driver.get field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting JSON data this way is suboptimal. It will do exactly the same thing as if you were to do it with your browser. Selenium *will* get the data but it will appear as a browser page and you'll still have to *get it from the browser* to do anything with it. I'd use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to get that data rather than go through Selenium.

At any rate, if what you are trying to do is build a URL, then Selenium won't do it *for you*. You have to do it before calling `driver.get`:

```
driver.get("https://" + d["server"] + "/test")
```

I'm not sure what `sep=''` is meant to be. I interpreted it as specifying a separator between the earlier arguments you had. If so, then it is not needed. Otherwise, you'll have to clarify.

Comment: Ahh thanks thats works but it's not opening up separate display's it's just overwriting

Comment: You asked a question about a specific error message, which you received answers for. What you are pointing out in your comment here is a problem related to the same piece of code but it is a different problem. You should ask a new question for it, that focuses on *this new problem* and explains in detail what you want and what you expect. I strongly recommend *against* editing your question here because a) you've already got answers and b) it would make your question less useful to others and less likely to get upvotes over time.

Comment: Sorry was trying to kill two birds with one stone as it were

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create the display and driver only once most likely, and then only `get` within the loop:

```
display = Display(visible=1, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for d in data["screen"]:
    driver.get("https://",d["server"],"/test",sep='')
    print(driver.page_source)
```

I'm assuming you come from R with that `sep=''`; in Python you can concatenate with `+`, that is:

```
driver.get("https://" + d["server"] + "/test")
```

As @Louis suggested, you can possibly also just use the requests module if your data is not loaded by javascript (and the page does not require javascript to be enabled):

```
import requests
for d in data["screen"]:
    response = requests.get("https://" + d["server"] + "/test")
    print(response.content)
```